# How to create a new action in Zend 2 by command line?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-tool

I know in zf1 we can use command line to create action like below:
zf create action

But in Zend 2, I can't find a command line which can create a new action.
Is that removed, or maybe a new command can do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "new" ZFTool in ZF2

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html

What should be the benefit of "create action"? It's just a function and a view script. So, simply create it.

Comment: I see, but I always use zf tool commandline in ZF1 to create action/module/controller... It's very convenient

Comment: Of course it is (was). Maybe they improve "ZF2Tool" in future. In the very early releases there wasn't any cli for ZF2.